# How to non display dialog in tortoise cleanup?

Tags: svn, dialog, tortoisesvn, task, resource-cleanup

I run some scheduled tasks for svn on my local computer like: update.
Sometimes update cannot run for cleanup problem, so I have add scheduled task for cleanup, but it cannot run without my intervention: always dispalys dialog:

[image]

How to non display this dialog? Really I change nothing - only click button ok.

Thanks.

Comment: And if you have to use cleanup often, you have to see at your case (host, FS, Working Copy) more deeply. `svn cleanup` is a tool of last resort and final hope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseSVN doesn't seem to be a good tool for automation.

Consider using command line svn:

```
svn cleanup
```

will do what you need

Comment: Additionally, recent TortoiseSVN releases include the command line utilities as an optional install.

Answer (score 5):

A quick look at the [docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html#tsvn-automation-basics) help:

> Use **/noui** to prevent the result dialog from popping up (either telling about the cleanup being finished or showing an error message). **/noprogressui** also disables the progress dialog. **/nodlg** disables showing the cleanup dialog where the user can choose what exactly should be done in the cleanup. The available actions can be specified with the options /cleanup for status cleanup, /revert, /delunversioned, /delignored, /refreshshell and /externals.